# Twitter feed widget not working

Tags: twitter, widget, feed, twitter-feed

Hello I am having some issue with the Twitter Feed Widget. After editing it I copy the code and put it on my page:

```
    <div>
      <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TimIDCA" data-widget-id="302125789070102528">Tweets by @TimIDCA</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

but this error pops up in my console:

> Failed to load resource http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/302125789070102528?domai…ack=twttr.tfw.callbacks.tl_302125789070102528&suppress_response_codes=true

What do I do?

The only thing that shows up is the link: Tweets by @TimIDCA

Answer (score 0):

Go back to twitter where you configured the widget and set the domain you intend to use the widget in. You can list multiple domains. For example:

```
*.stewardxpress.com, *.ihnbc.com
```

Where * is a wildcard for any subdomain you might have and want to apply the widget to. Reload and it should be working. At least, I've fixed two non-functional widgets by doing just this.

Comment: where is this option in the Twitter widget settings??